# Udacity's finish daysBetweenDates answer might be wrong

Tags: python

There might be a bug in this lesson.

I'm trying to move forward without needing to watch the answer videos for the daysBetweenDates quiz.

Long story short:
I figured out the code and it works for all test cases, except one.
The error was odd. The difference between the number of days between dates I got and the answer according to Udacity. My notion is that if there's error in my code, the difference between the answer I got and Udacity's expected answer would be more than 1 because the error should be recurring.

I tried to compute the number of days between dates using a different approach. I got the number my program computed.

So the question is, is the number of days between dates between 1900,1 ,1 and 1999,12, 31 really 36523(Udacity's answer) or 36524(my answer)

Here's my complete code

I recommend you try it on your interpreter to check if Udacity's answer for the last test case is correct.

```
# Credit goes to Websten from forums
#
# Use Dave's suggestions to finish your daysBetweenDates
# procedure. It will need to take into account leap years
# in addition to the correct number of days in each month.

number_of_days_in_month = 30

def nextDay(year, month, day):
    """Simple version: assume every month has 30 days"""
    number_of_days_in_month = setDaysInMonth(month, year)
    if day < number_of_days_in_month:
        return year, month, day + 1
    else:
        if month == 12:
            return year + 1, 1, 1
        else:
            return year, month + 1, 1

def dateIsBefore(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    """Returns True if year1-month1-day1 is before year2-month2-day2. Otherwise, returns False."""
    if year1 < year2:
        return True
    if year1 == year2:
        if month1 < month2:
            return True
        if month1 == month2:
            return day1 < day2
    return False        

def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    """Returns the number of days between year1/month1/day1
       and year2/month2/day2. Assumes inputs are valid dates
       in Gregorian calendar."""
    # program defensively! Add an assertion if the input is not valid!
    assert not dateIsBefore(year2, month2, day2, year1, month1, day1)
    number_of_days_between_dates = 0
    while dateIsBefore(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
        year1, month1, day1 = nextDay(year1, month1, day1)
        number_of_days_between_dates += 1
    print number_of_days_between_dates
    return number_of_days_between_dates



def setDaysInMonth(month1, year1):
    if isLeapYear(year1) == False:
        if month1 == 1:
            number_of_days_in_month = 31
        if month1 == 3:
            number_of_days_in_month = 31
        if month1 == 5:
            number_of_days_in_month = 31
        if month1 == 7:
            number_of_days_in_month = 31
        if month1 == 8:
            number_of_days_in_month = 31
        if month1 == 10:
            number_of_days_in_month = 31
        if month1 == 12:
            number_of_days_in_month = 31
        if month1 == 4:
            number_of_days_in_month = 30
        if month1 == 6:
            number_of_days_in_month = 30
        if month1 == 9:
            number_of_days_in_month = 30
        if month1 == 11:
            number_of_days_in_month = 30
        if month1 == 2:
            number_of_days_in_month = 28
        return number_of_days_in_month
    else:
        if month1 == 1:
            number_of_days_in_month = 31
        if month1 == 3:
            number_of_days_in_month = 31
        if month1 == 5:
            number_of_days_in_month = 31
        if month1 == 7:
            number_of_days_in_month = 31
        if month1 == 8:
            number_of_days_in_month = 31
        if month1 == 10:
            number_of_days_in_month = 31
        if month1 == 12:
            number_of_days_in_month = 31
        if month1 == 4:
            number_of_days_in_month = 30
        if month1 == 6:
            number_of_days_in_month = 30
        if month1 == 9:
            number_of_days_in_month = 30
        if month1 == 11:
            number_of_days_in_month = 30
        if month1 == 2:
            number_of_days_in_month = 29
        return number_of_days_in_month

def isLeapYear(year1):
    if year1 % 4 == 0:
        return True
    return False

def numberOfLeapYears(year1, year2):
    number_of_leap_years = 0

    while year1 < year2:
        if year1 % 4 == 0:
            number_of_leap_years += 1
            year1 += 1
        else:
            year1 += 1
    #print "number of leap years: " + str(number_of_leap_years)
    return number_of_leap_years

def numberOfNonLeapYears(year1, year2):
    number_of_non_leap_years = 0
    while year1 < year2:
        if year1 % 4 == 0:            
            year1 += 1
        else:
            number_of_non_leap_years += 1
            year1 += 1
    #print "number of non leap years: " + str(number_of_non_leap_years)
    return number_of_non_leap_years


def numberOfDays(year1, year2):
    number_of_leap_years = numberOfLeapYears(year1, year2)
    print number_of_leap_years
    number_of_non_leap_years = numberOfNonLeapYears(year1, year2)
    print number_of_non_leap_years
    number_of_days = 0
    number_of_days = number_of_leap_years * 366 + number_of_non_leap_years * 365
    #print number_of_days
    return number_of_days



def test():
    test_cases = [((2012,1,1,2012,2,28), 58), 
                  ((2012,1,1,2012,3,1), 60),
                  ((2011,6,30,2012,6,30), 366),
                  ((2011,1,1,2012,8,8), 585 ),
                  ((1900,1,1,1999,12,31), 36523),
                  ((1900,1,1,1910,1,1), 3653)]

    for (args, answer) in test_cases:
        result = daysBetweenDates(*args)
        if result != answer:
            print "Test with data:", args, "failed"
        else:
            print "Test case passed!"

test()

#print isLeapYear(1900)
#print 366*3 + 365*7
#print numberOfLeapYears(1900, 1999)
#print numberOfNonLeapYears(1900, 1999)
print numberOfDays(1900, 2000)
```

Comment: Sorry, mate. You are wrong. [1900 is not a leap year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century_leap_year)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a naive test for Leap Year ( %4). But there are additional rules to leap years.

Leap year is any year evenly divisible by 4, unless it is divisible by 100 (then it is not a leap year), unless it is divisible by 400 (Then it is a leap year).

Thus 1500, 1700, 1800, 1900 were not leaps years but 1600 and 2000 were leap years.

A simple Python version:

```
def is_leap_year(year):
    if year % 400 == 0:
        return True
    if year % 4 == 0 and not year % 100 == 0:
        return True
    return False
```